# XSL Conditional Totalling

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

Is it possible to perform conditional totalling in xsl?

I have the following xml sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<export>
<stats set="1">
  <columns>
    <column id="0">
      <sum>100</sum>
    </column>
    <column id="1">
      <sum>102</sum>
    </column>
    <column id="2">
      <sum>12</sum>
    </column>
  </columns>
</stats>
  <stats set="2">
    <columns>
      <column id="0">
        <sum>100</sum>
      </column>
      <column id="1">
        <sum>101</sum>
      </column>
      <column id="2">
        <sum>19</sum>
      </column>
    </columns>
  </stats>
</export>
```

Is it possible to compute the total of all columns in each stat set where they are not equal to one another?  So it would output the following:

```
               Set 1       Set 2       Diff(Set 1 - Set 2)
Total (Diff)   114         120           -6
column 2       102         101            1  
column 3       12          19            -7
```

So in the output column 1 would be omitted as the sum in the two stat sets is the same.

I can get my xsl to output the columns that are different but unsure how to total these up and put in the total row.

Many thanks,

Andez

Comment: Edit your post to include your XSL

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete and efficient solution and for extensive explanations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation** (64 lines):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:key name="kColByPosAndVal" match="column"
  use="concat(count(preceding-sibling::*),
              '+',
              sum)"/>
 <xsl:key name="kIdByVal" match="column/@id"
  use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vsum1" select=
   "sum(stats[@set=1]/*/column
                  [not(key('kColByPosAndVal',
                            concat(count(preceding-sibling::*),
                                  '+',
                                   sum)
                           )[2]
                       )])"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vsum2" select=
   "sum(stats[@set=2]/*/column
                  [not(key('kColByPosAndVal',
                            concat(count(preceding-sibling::*),
                                  '+',
                                   sum)
                           )[2]
                       )])"/>

                 Set 1          Set 2       Diff(Set 1 - Set 2)
  Total (Diff)   <xsl:text/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vsum1"/>
  <xsl:text>             </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vsum2"/>
  <xsl:text>             </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="$vsum1 -$vsum2"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:for-each select=
   "*/*/column/@id
       [generate-id()
       = generate-id(key('kIdByVal',.)[1])
       ]
       [not(key('kColByPosAndVal',
                concat(count(../preceding-sibling::*),
                       '+',
                       ../sum)
                )[2]
            )]">
    <xsl:variable name="vcolSet1" select=
     "/*/stats[@set=1]/*/column[@id=current()]/sum"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vcolSet2" select=
     "/*/stats[@set=2]/*/column[@id=current()]/sum"/>
  Column <xsl:value-of select=".+1"/><xsl:text/>
    <xsl:text>       </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vcolSet1"/>
    <xsl:text>             </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vcolSet2"/>
    <xsl:text>             </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$vcolSet1 -$vcolSet2"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<export>
<stats set="1">
  <columns>
    <column id="0">
      <sum>100</sum>
    </column>
    <column id="1">
      <sum>102</sum>
    </column>
    <column id="2">
      <sum>12</sum>
    </column>
  </columns>
</stats>
  <stats set="2">
    <columns>
      <column id="0">
        <sum>100</sum>
      </column>
      <column id="1">
        <sum>101</sum>
      </column>
      <column id="2">
        <sum>19</sum>
      </column>
    </columns>
  </stats>
</export>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
                 Set 1          Set 2       Diff(Set 1 - Set 2)
  Total (Diff)   114             120             -6

  Column 2       102             101             1

  Column 3       12             19             -7
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The key named `kColByPosAndVal` is used to select all columns that have a given position (among all `column` siblings) and a given value for their `sum`** child-element.
2. **The key named `kIdByVal` is used in Muenchian grouping to find all different values for the `id` attribute**.
3. **The two totals are calculated summing only those columns, whose `kColByPosAndVal` key selects only one `column` element** (if it selects two `column` elements, they both are at the same position and have the same `sum`).
4. **The rest should be easy to understand**.

Comment: Thanks for that Dimitre.  I will try it out shortly.

Comment: sorry the workload just went through the roof so I had to put this on the back burner.  I am only just starting to look at this now

Comment: excellent thank you.  I have had a play around and it does what I was hoping.  Also, thanks for the explanations - they do help - I'm still relatively new to XSL.  Cheers Andez